# Como llamar TextView desde ActivityDataSource

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo una consulta para ver que no se repita el codigo de articulo pero no encuentro la manera de llamar al TextView de la otra clase`introducir el código aquí. He probado de hacer la consulta en el Activity pero no puedo llamar dbRead(SQLiteDatabase)

```
public boolean ComprobarCodiArticulo(long id){
    boolean Existe = true;

    Cursor resultadoSelect = dbRead.rawQuery("SELECT " + ARTICLES_codiArticulo + " FROM " + table_ARTICLES + " WHERE " + ARTICLES_codiArticulo + "=" + LLAMAR A TEXTVIEW, null);

    if(resultadoSelect.getCount()<=0){
        Existe =false;
    }
    else{
        Existe =true;
    }
    return Existe ;
}
```

---

```
if(bd.ComprobarCodiArticulo(idTask) == true){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Este codigo ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

`

Comment: la otra clase que contiene el textView es una Activity?, debes poder llamar dbRead desde otra clase, como la instancias?

Comment: Si, es una activity, pero tengo que crear el dbRead tambien en el activity o lo tengo que llamar?

Comment: Agrega la clase que instancia dbRead.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora si! Cada vez que quiera hacer una consulta lo tengo que hacer en el activity o lo puedo hacer en el DataSource?

Comment: Te sugiero agregues las clases completas, tanto del Activity como de la que contiene el método ComprobarCodiArticulo()